# Float vs Decimal in C

Tags: c, floating-point, double, floating-point-precision

The following piece of code :

```
int main()
{
float a=0.7;
printf("%.10f %.10f\n",0.7, a);
return 0;
}
```

gives 0.7000000000 0.6999999881 as answer while the following piece of code :

```
int main()
{
float a=1.7;
printf("%.10f %.10f\n",1.7, a);
return 0;
}
```

gives 1.7000000000 1.7000000477 as output.

Why is that in the first case upon printing a I got a value less than 0.7 and in the second case more than 1.7?

Comment: Read [this article about floating point precision](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a floating-point constant to `printf`, it is passed as a `double`.

So it is not the same as passing a `float` variable with "the same" value to `printf`.

Change this constant value to `0.7f` (or `1.7f`), and you'll get the same results.

Alternatively, change `float a` to `double a`, and you'll also get the same results.

---

**Option #1:**

```
double a = 0.7;
printf("%.10f %.10f\n",0.7,a);
// Passing two double values to printf
```

**Option #2:**

```
float a = 0.7;
printf("%.10f %.10f\n",0.7f,a);
// Expanding two float values to double values and passing them to printf
```